# Traefik | No Certificate for a single Domain

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik, certbot

I use Traefik with docker-compose. All domains automatically receive a certificate via Lets Encrypt.

But now I need an SSL certificate for an external application. This Application is not connected to traefik, but is running on the same Server.

In order to use Certbot for this task, a domain without a certificate must be able to accept connections via http.In order for Certbot to work, it tries to save a file in the root directory of the domain and access it via http.

Can you prevent the use of SSL via label?

Relevant Part of the Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: traefik:1.7.20-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
        #- "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    networks:
      - webserver

  node-Domain:
    image: httpd:latest
    networks:
      - webserver
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:node.domain.tld"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.application.tls=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=false"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    volumes:
      - ./node-Domain:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve... Looks like you are using traefik v1, juding from the labels... Can you provide more details about your traefik version and the external application? For example, is the external application hosted on the same servers? Is the provided `docker-compose` config contains only the external application or is the traefik running as a docker container? Please update your question with these details if possible.

Comment: Done. I hope that's all you need

Comment: Just to make sure I understand properly. So, `node-Domain` is not the external application. And You need to host a completely different application. But traefik is published/bound to ports using port config "80:80" & "443:443". That means any and every connection via ports `80`, and `443` of the host will be intercepted by traefik. So, you will either have to use traefik to host the application or stop the traefik container or use different ports for your external application.

Comment: The application uses a different port, but requires an SSL certificate.
To get the certificate automatically, I need Certbot. Certbot can only issue a certificate if the domain can be accessed via http: //.

Comment: As from your docker-compose file, that the traefik container doesn't have any labels, and I can assume that they are defined in a config file. You need to disable redirection to https in your config file, rather than using label for `node-Domain` container. These labels are container specific.